# How to make relative import work with dot inside a python package?

Tags: python, import, package

I have a folder named as "model_dir" contains multiple *.py files.

model_dir:

"model.py"

"utils.py"

inside model.py I can import like this: from `utils import test`

I want to copy the whole folder inside a package. Currently to make the import works inside the package I have two options:

1- adding folder path to sys.path

2- add dot for imports, like this: `from .utils import test`

Is there any way to make imports work without changing the code or sys path?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried including a blank __init__.py file in the model_dir folder? That should let python files import sibling files- I'm a novice dev myself and often run into pitfalls with imports inside packages, and I've found [this link](https://docs.python-guide.org/writing/structure/)
to be pretty helpful figuring out what I've done wrong

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).